# xml2: How to convert an xml object to string (in memory, as R object)

Tags: r, xml2

I have the following situation:

- I parse an xml file using `xml2::read_xml`
- I change some content in the xml document. The details are not relevant for the question.
- Now I want to send the manipulated xml data to an API. Therefore I need a text represantation of that xml data. For this purpose, the XML package had the function `XML::toString`. I cannot find an equivalent in the xml2-Package. Therefore I do it like this:

  ```
  tmpfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".xml")
  xml2::write_xml(xml, file = tmpfile)
  txt <- readLines(tmpfile, encoding = "UTF-8")
  file.remove(tmpfile)
  call_api(txt)
  ```
- I am doing this for several hundret files.

Writing to disk something that could be done in memory is very inefficient.

Am I missing an obvious function in the xml2 package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xml2` package provides `as.character()` methods for its object classes. So, using a built-in example, you can simply do:

```
library(xml2)
dat <- read_xml(xml2_example("order-doc.xml"))

as.character(dat)
[1] "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<purchaseOrder xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/po.xsd\" orderDate=\"1999-10-20\">\n  <shipTo country=\"US\">\n    <name>Alice Smith</name>\n    <street>123 Maple Street</street>\n    <city>Mill Valley</city>\n    <state>CA</state>\n    <zip>90952</zip>\n  </shipTo>\n  <billTo country=\"US\">\n    <name>Robert Smith</name>\n    <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>\n    <city>Old Town</city>\n    <state>PA</state>\n    <zip>95819</zip>\n  </billTo>\n  <comment>Hurry, my lawn is going wild!</comment>\n  <items>\n    <item partNum=\"872-AA\">\n      <productName>Lawnmower</productName>\n      <quantity>1</quantity>\n      <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>\n      <comment>Confirm this is electric</comment>\n    </item>\n    <item partNum=\"926-AA\">\n      <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>\n      <quantity>1</quantity>\n      <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>\n      <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>\n    </item>\n  </items>\n</purchaseOrder>\n"
```

Note also that because the default `toString()` method first coerces to character, you could also use that.

```
identical(toString(dat), as.character(dat))
[1] TRUE
```